# Including my own global vars and php functions in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, global-variables

I´m trying to include mi own functions in joomla code to set the header and footer of the home page of my site, As I can see, including php files works fine, but functions can not acces vars outside them.

For example:

```
function test () {
     echo 'ok';
}
```

works without problems, but:

```
$test = 'ok';
function test () {
     global $test;
     echo $test;
}
```

does not work, so, when I call a file wich contains the functions, most of them require global variables located outside them, therefor they dont`t work as in the example I typed.

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is not working? Your syntax looks correct, do you mean to echo $test inside the function?

Comment: Is this using DirectPHP by chance?

Answer (score 3):

Its probably going to depend on where you call the file from.

From my understanding Joomla follows an MVC structure so if you include you functions in a template they are actually being included in a method that will call/render the actual view template. Therefore if something is in a completely separate view rendering call i would imagine the same var may not be available and even if it is it ma not be the same value as you are expecting.

What you probably need to do is [develop a Module, Component, or Plugin in the appropriate fashion](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers) and go about making certain things available throughout the system where you need to use them.

Answer (score 2):

add $ to echo $test;

```
$test = 'ok';
function test () {
   global $test;
   echo $test;
}
```

Comment: yups, I´m sorry it was a mistake in the question :)